# Retrieving deal stage probabilities via HubSpot API

Tags: vba, hubspot, hubspot-api

I'm currently using VBA to interact with the HubSpot API (but I assume this question can also be answered by someone who is not familiar with VBA but knows the HubSpot API) and retrieve data about my deals. My existing function works flawlessly and allows me to fetch data from the `/crm/v3/objects/deals` endpoint.

However, there is a feature in HubSpot where I can assign a closing probability to each deal stage (for example, "qualifiedtobuy" could have a 40% closing probability). I would very much like to fetch it programmatically.

[image: HubSpot: Dealstages. Adjust closing probability]

I've scoured the HubSpot API documentation but haven't found a clear answer on whether or how I can fetch this deal stage probability data via the API. Would anyone here happen to know if this is possible, and if so, could you provide some guidance or point me to the relevant API endpoints or documentation?

Here's the function I'm currently using for reference:

```
Function GetHubspotDealData() As String
    Dim objHttp As Object
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp")
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sSecretToken As String
    sSecretToken = "my-secret-token"
    sUrl = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals"
    objHttp.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & sSecretToken
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objHttp.send
    GetHubspotDealData = objHttp.responseText
End Function
```

Any insights or even small hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the right ideas from @Saeven, I was now able to solve the issue. I simply had to replace the endpoint `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals` with the correct endpoint `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/pipelines/deals`. This will result in a JSON response containing all deal stages with their set names, internal names, display order, closing status, probabilities and some more information.

This is a working code example:

```
Function GetHubspotDealStageProbabilities() As String
    Dim objHttp As Object
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp")
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sSecretToken As String
    sSecretToken = "my-secret-token"
    sUrl = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/pipelines/deals"
    objHttp.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & sSecretToken
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objHttp.send
    GetHubspotDealStageProbabilities= objHttp.responseText
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 'hs_deal_stage_probability'.  You can find the property label for any property:

1. Click on the gear icon top right
2. Select Objects > Deals
3. Click on "Manage Deal Properties"
4. Filter for the property you seek
5. Click on the little code/caret icon they use, and it reveals the system name

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! That was definitely useful. While it did not solve my problem completely, it at least brought me on the right track and I found the right endpoint https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/pipelines/deals